# How to get default camera storage location when the photo is taken?

Tags: java, android, image, camera, storage

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Above code is to get the absolute path of the sd card. But I don't know how to get the storage location of the picture which is taken using in-built camera in android phone.

Can anyone give me a possible code for this question .

Comment: How are you taking picture exactly, are you starting the camera Intent from your activity and getting the result in onActivityResult?

Comment: My task is to get the pictures which are taken only using default camera and then display only that images in the listview.

Comment: yes just like @DougStevenson posted in his answer use `Enviroment.DIRECTORY_DCIM` to get pictures taken only by Camera (ideally)

Comment: Using that method it displays as DCIM, inside that i have many folders. My camera pictures are storing inside `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO/sdsd.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

It's also in the Environment class.  See the [javadoc for Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DCIM).  You pass that value to [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) to get the final directory.

Comment: I don't know how to get storage location of the camera

Comment: `String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM;` It displays as DCIM , but inside this i have several folders.

Comment: Sorry, you pass that value to another function.  Updated my answer.